# ImportError: No module named 'kafka' in databricks pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am not able to use the kafka library in the databricks notebook.

getting the error
`ImportError: No module named 'kafka'`

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
def send_to_kafka(rows):
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers = "localhost:9092")
    for row in rows:
        producer.send('topic', str(row.asDict()))  
        producer.flush()

df.foreachPartition(send_to_kafka)
```

**databricks cluster info**

spark version - `2.4.3`

scala version - `2.11`

Help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this - it's very inefficient, just use [`kafka` connector to write data](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-the-output-of-batch-queries-to-kafka), like this (you need first convert data into JSON string):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_json, struct
df.select(to_json(struct("*")).alias("value"))\
  .write.format("kafka")\
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")\
  .option("topic", "topic1")\
  .save()
```

Comment: Getting the error. @Alex Ott

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<command-2282>", line 4
    .write.format("kafka")
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: fixed - forgot to add `\` in one place

Comment: Now getting error :

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/connector/catalog/TableProvider

Comment: what Databricks runtime are you using? Or you're using Light version?  Use just normal Databricks runtime - 7.x for example - the code definitely works there

Answer (score 0):

The file is not in the right directory, or in wrong place. Or, you never installed it but  I do not think that is a downloadable module.

Comment: Yes it is not installed . Its a python package named "kafka". The official python kafka client.

Comment: But the problem is Im not able to download it from the kafka-python official documentation as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure python dependencies are available on all executor nodes.
There are following options:

a) Run a bootstrap package install script on all executor nodes before launching a cluster. E.g. run `pip install kafka` on all nodes. (Preferably use a dependency management solution)

b) Install the packages locally. Use one of the pyspark options for shipping dependcies to nodes:
`--py-files`, `--archive`.

c) Package the complete python interpreter among with all local installed dependencies with pex. Configure spark to use the python interpreter form the packaged pex archive.

See Spark User Guide: [Python Packaging](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html)